# Null Pointer that makes no sense to me?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Im currently working on a program and any time i call Products[1] there is no null pointer error however, when i call Products[0] or Products[2] i get a null pointer error. However i am still getting 2 different outputs almost like there is a [0] and 1 or 1 and 2 in the array. Here is my code

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader(location);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String [] data = new String[numberOfLines];
    Products = new Product[numberOfLines];
    calc = new Calculator();

    int prod_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        data = reader.readLine().split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+at\\s+");
        if(data[i].contains("input"))
        {
            continue;
        }
        Products[prod_count] = new Product();
        Products[prod_count].setName(data[1]);
        System.out.println(Products[prod_count].getName());
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(data[2]);
        Products[prod_count].setPrice(price);


        for(String dataSt : data)
        {

            if(dataSt.toLowerCase().contains("imported"))
        {
                Products[prod_count].setImported(true);
        }
            else{
                Products[prod_count].setImported(false);
            }

        }



        calc.calculateTax(Products[prod_count]);    
        calc.calculateItemTotal(Products[prod_count]);
        prod_count++;
```

This is the output :

```
imported box of chocolates
1.50
11.50
imported bottle of perfume
7.12
54.62
```

This print works `System.out.println(Products[1].getProductTotal());`

This becomes a null pointer `System.out.println(Products[2].getProductTotal());`

This also becomes a null pointer `System.out.println(Products[0].getProductTotal());`

Comment: What value does `readLines()` return?

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: readLines() returns an int representing how many lines are in the file

Comment: and David i have used the debugger its saying that i have a null pointer on any spots where i call [2] or [0] in that array. The thing im not understand is how i get two outputs from the array for calculate Tax() and calculateItemTotal() yet when calling Products[1].getItemTotal i only get one and when i try calling 2 i get a null pointer error

Comment: @user2786754 Debug through the outer for loop. Does execution go in to the `if` statement with the `continue`?

Comment: Just post some of your input please.

Comment: this is the input and yes it does Input 2:
1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00
1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50

Answer (score 3):

You're skipping lines containing "input".

```
if(data[i].contains("input")) {
    continue;          // Products[i] will be null
}
```

Probably it would be better to make `products` an ArrayList, and add only the meaningful rows to it.

`products` should also start with lowercase to follow Java conventions. Types start with uppercase, parameters & variables start with lowercase. Not all Java coding conventions are perfect -- but this one's very useful.

The code is otherwise structured fine, but arrays are not a very flexible type to build from program logic (since the length has to be pre-determined, skipping requires you to keep track of the index, and it can't track the size as you build it).

Generally you should build List (ArrayList). Map (HashMap, LinkedHashMap, TreeMap) and Set (HashSet) can be useful too.

---

Second bug:  as Bohemian says: in `data[]` you've confused the concepts of a list of all lines, and `data[]` being the tokens parsed/ split from a single line.

"data" is generally a meaningless term. Use meaningful terms/names & your programs are far less likely to have bugs in them.

You should probably just use `tokens` for the line tokens, not declare it outside/ before it is needed, and not try to index it by line -- because, quite simply, there should be absolutely no need to.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    // we shouldn't need data[] for all lines,  and we weren't using it as such.
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+at\\s+");
    //
    if (tokens[0].equals("input")) {        // unclear which you actually mean.
    /* if (line.contains("input")) { */    
        continue;
    }
```

When you offer sample input for a question, edit it into the body of the question so it's readable. Putting it in the comments, where it can't be read properly, is just wasting the time of people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Yes its suppossed to do that as the input comes as follows Input 2:
1 imported box of chocolates at 10.00
1 imported bottle of perfume at 47.50

Comment: So how does that make it so even though 2 outputs show up skipping that first line makes both 0 space in the array and 2 space in the array empty? and 3 space in the array is out of bounds?

Answer (score 2):

Bug alert: You are overwriting `data`:

```
String [] data = new String[numberOfLines];
```

then in the loop:

```
data = reader.readLine().split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+at\\s+");
```

So who knows how large it is - depends on the success of the split - but your code relies on it being `numberOfLines` long.

Comment: Correct, there are major bugs here. It appears `data` should be used as the tokens within a single line, but is initially declared & at one point (the "skip input" check) is indexed by line number. It should be `tokens` for a single line. _In general, variables should not be declared/sized before they are needed._

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different indexes for the line number and the new product objects.  If you have 20 lines but 5 of them are "input" then you only have 15 new product objects.

For example:

```
int prod_count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
{
        data = reader.readLine().split("(?<=\\d)\\s+|\\s+at\\s+");
        if (data[i].contains("input"))
        {
            continue;
        }
        Products[prod_count] = new Product();
        Products[prod_count].setName(data[1]);
        // etc.
        prod_count++; // last thing to do
}
```

Comment: jarmod i still am getting a null pointer at index any index greater than 0 however your solution did turn the usable product into the index of 0.

Comment: Are you accessing Products[1] (and higher) *before* you have created them?  If so, they will be null and cause nullpointerexception.  You cannot access Products[1] until you have executed Products[prod_count] = new Product() *where* prod_count is 1.